# Function for adding a tag to the first row of a table is running slowly

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

I have a jQuery function which adds a tag to the first row of a table. I previously tried using append, however that didn't work. I now have the following solution which is very slow and it gives this warning:

> A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly

Function:

```
jQuery.fn.fixGridView = function () {
    "use strict";
   // var start = +new Date();  // log start timestamp 
    if (jQuery(this).is('table') && this.find('thead').length === 0) {

        var theadv = "<thead><tr>" + this.find('tbody tr:first').html(); +"</tr></thead>";

        this.find('tbody tr:first').remove();
        var htmlv = this.html();
        this.html(theadv + htmlv);
    }
    //var end = +new Date();  // log end timestamp
   // var diff = end - start;
   // alert(diff);
    return this;
};
```

I have to use IE8, it is client's requirement.
I have also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xLzL/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you just want to wrap the first as `<thead>` and the rest in `<tbody>`. Why it's slow:

- `html()` is one possible cause. That's because you're reconstructing the DOM rather than reusing what's there already.
- `find()` is a descendant lookup function. It looks for elements deep into the tree. If  you know that the element is a few levels down, then use multiple `children()` calls instead which only searches one level deep.
- Just to add, attribute selectors like `[id*="gvCategories"]` are very slow. Better to use multiple classes instead, like `class="MainContent gvCategories"`. That way, you can do `$('.gvCategories')`, which is faster.

**The fastest and most painless fix is to just write the HTML with the first row in a `<thead>`**. Plain and simple.

If you really want to go with JS, then [here's my take on it](http://jsfiddle.net/4xLzL/9/) and the [performance test to prove it](http://jsperf.com/detatch-to-thead)

```
jQuery.fn.fixGridView = function () {
    "use strict";

    // A jQuery object may be more than one element. Operate on each  using each()
    // Additionally, return the result to allow chainability.
    return this.each(function () {
        // Cache the element to avoid doing DOM refetch
        var element = $(this);
        if (!element.is('table')) return;  

        // No need for tbody, since the browser automatically adds it
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/938143/575527

        // Now we avoid using find() since it looks for all descendants.
        // Instead, we use children() to limit our search to 2 levels of children
        var rows = element.children('tbody').children('tr');
        var thead = element.children('thead').length;

        // Get the first row, wrap it in <thead>, and prepend it to the table
        if(!thead) rows.eq(0).wrap('<thead/>').parent().prependTo(element);


    });

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gvCategories').fixGridView();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Joseph the Dreamer.. This is very fast now, however i still get the error saying "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly". I am using JQuery table-sorter, can it be the reason to make my page slow? I have only 50-55 records in my table..

Comment: @user1181942 Can't really tell and I don't have much experience debugging in IE8. You could try profiling your code in Chrome or Firefox with their dev tools to see which code is taking long to execute. Then fix that part of the code, and then try again on IE8.

Comment: ..Yes..I will try that.. Nyways thanks.. You made my code super-fast..